# What does the circle with the “X” and the cross mean?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, adc, dsp, diagram

I am taking a look at a DSP block for a the Xilinx ZCU111 FPGA and I am getting held up on a simple question. I come from physics so I am not too used to looking at block diagrams yet, but what do the highlighted components in the block indicate within the fine mixer?

[image: Block Diagram for RFSoC FPGA DSP]

Comment: Multiplication and addition.

Comment: @user_1818839 Got it, so that would mean the multiplexed NCO signal is being multiplied by I_in and being added to NCO x Q_in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are mixers and summing amplifiers.

[image: Basic architecture of a complex transmitter from Microwave Journal]

<sub>(Image source: [Microwave Journal - *Complex RF Mixers, Zero IF Architecture, and Advanced Algorithms: The Black Magic in Next-Generation SDR Transceivers*, Figure 3. Basic architecture of a complex transmitter](https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/29171-complex-rf-mixers-zero-if-architecture-and-advanced-algorithms-the-black-magic-in-next-generation-sdr-transceivers))</sub>

Comment: Question is about a digital path, not RF.  I'm curious if anyone in the digital world would call it a "summing amplifier"?